# Sorting dictionary in descending order

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, i need to sort it on the descending order of the MI Value.And print the contents in dict one by one in descending order along with 'hi'

My coding:

```
d = dict()
for item in a:
    specificy = c[item]
    MI1= specificx/float(specificy)
    MI2= MI1*specificx
    M13= specificx*specificy
    MI = MI1* math.log(MI1/float(MI2))
    d[x + ' ' + item] = MI

print d    
for k,v in d:
    print k + v + 'hi'
```

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
import operator
for k in sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print(k + d[k] + 'hi')
```

It works by getting the items of the dictionary, sorting them by the values, reversed, then printing that.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/565635

Answer (score 0):

To sort using key change index of x to 0

```
for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False):
    print k + v + 'hi'
```

To sort using value change index of x to 1

```
for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False):
    print k + v + 'hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort a dictionary on the item **value** you can use

```
sorted(d, key=d.__getitem__)
```

In your case the code becomes

```
for k in sorted(d, key=d.__getitem__, reverse=True):
    print(k + d[k] + "hi")
```

### Explanation

When in Python you write

```
d[k]
```

what is evaluated is

```
d.__getitem__(k)
```

so `d.__getitem__` when `d` is a dictionary is a function that given a key returns the value associated to that key in the dictionary.

`sorted` instead is a predefined function that returns a sorted version of a sequence and accepts an optional parameter (named somewhat unfortunately `key`, but note that key has no relation to dictionaries here). This parameter can be used to determine **on what** the ordering comparison should be done; `sorted` also supports another optional parameter `reversed` where you can determine if ascendant or descendant sorting is required.

Finally when a dictionary is used as a sequence (for example passing it to `sorted` or iterating over it in a `for`) what you obtain are the **keys** of the dictionary.

This for example implies that `sorted(d, key=d.__getitem__)` returns the keys of the dictionary sorted according the value.