# Python - Sorting Dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with this Python. I'm trying to sort a dictionary alphabetically, from min to max (with values) and from max to min (by values). How can I do this?

Note: I can't get max to min working

```
stocks = {
    'GOOG': 520.24,
    'FB': 331.28,
    'XMZN': 89.72,
    'APPL': 112.31
}

# for min to max
print(sorted(zip(stocks.values(), stocks.keys())))

# for alphabetically
print(sorted(zip(stocks.keys(), stocks.values())))

# for max to min
print(sorted(zip(stocks.values(), stocks.keys(), reverse))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list sort in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 4):

Keyword arguments must be given a value, otherwise the identifier will be used as a name.

```
print(sorted(zip(stocks.values(), stocks.keys(), reverse=True))
```

Comment: up voted but possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order/4183540#4183540) :p

Answer (score 2):

```
stocks = {
'GOOG': 520.24,
'FB': 331.28,
'XMZN': 89.72,
'APPL': 112.31
}

print sorted(stocks.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
```

You can simply do this instead of `zip` and all

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the list using `[::-1`]

```
# for max to min
print(sorted(zip(stocks.values(), stocks.keys()))[::-1])
```

Output:

```
[(520.24, 'GOOG'), (331.28, 'FB'), (112.31, 'APPL'), (89.72, 'XMZN')]
```