# How do I make the tuple order the opposite way around?

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python so I need some help to setup my highest to lowest sorting system for a dictionary.
I use:

```
highestList = sorted(classFile.items(), key=lamda x: x[::-1])
```

This sorted my dictionary into a tuple but it is the wrong way around. it outputs:

```
[('Dylan', 4), ('Jimmy', 5), ('Mark', 5), ('Chris', 7)]
```

Where I would like it to output:

```
[('Chris', 7), ('Mark', 5), ('Jimmy',5), ('Dylan',4)]
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Python list sort in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4183506) . Voted to reopen by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
highestList = sorted(classFile.items(), key=lamda x: x[::-1],reverse=True)
```

Use `reverse=True`

Comment: `reverse` only there is no d