# Sort short_names in reverse alphabetic order

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I dont understand what I am doing wrong:

Sort short_names in reverse alphabetic order. Sample output from given program:

> ['Tod', 'Sam', 'Joe', 'Jan', 'Ann']

My code:

```
short_names = ['Jan', 'Sam', 'Ann', 'Joe', 'Tod']

short_names.sort()

print(short_names)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list sort in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 1):

`sort` function has a `reverse` option:

```
short_names.sort(reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, first have a look at the documentation for [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> `sort(*, key=None, reverse=None)`
>
> This method sorts the list in place, using only `<` comparisons between items.
>
> *reverse* is a boolean value. If set to True, then the list elements are sorted as if each comparison were reversed.

So the items in your list will be sorted from "smallest" to "largest" using the `<` comparion, which for strings means lexicographical ordering (A < AB < B). To sort it in reverse order, use the `reverse` parameter:

`short_names.sort(reverse=True)`

For more information have a look at the official [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/sorting.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
short_names.sort()
short_names.reverse()
```

Comment: Can you explain how/why is that different/better than the other answers here from 4 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
user_input = input()
short_names = user_input.split()

short_names.sort()
short_names.reverse()

print(short_names)
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm doing this lab right now, and this is what your code should look like for the zybook, based on the methods we have learned.

```
user_input = input()
short_names = user_input.split()
short_names.sort()
short_names.reverse()
print(short_names)
```

Comment: This question is over 5 years old, and there are already answers about using the `sort()` and `reverse()` methods. Please don't repeat answers.