# f.write list displaying backwards

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I made a word counter that counts all the words on a website and then writes them to a text file like this:

```
def create_dictionary(clean_word_list):
    word_count = {}
    f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
    for word in clean_word_list:
        if word in word_count:
            word_count[word] += 1
        else:
            word_count[word] = 1
    for key, value in sorted(word_count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
        f.write('{}-{}\n'.format(value, key))
    f.close()
```

The .txt file is displaying like this:

```
1-this

3-hey

7-item

13-its
```

How would i flip it to make it display like this?

```
13-its

7-item

3-hey

1-this
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list sort in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in `sorted` function takes a `reverse` keyword argument, that is `False` by default. You can make it `True` to reverse the sorting order:

```
sorted(word_count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```