# How will I adjust this piece of code to sort them from Highest -> Lowest, rather than Lowest -> Highest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to somehow change this piece of code from outputting from Smallest -> Highest, to Highest -> Smallest.

Code:

```
scores = []
with open("scoreboard.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split(',')
        score = int(score)
        scores.append((name, score))

scores.sort(key=lambda s: s[2])

for name, score in scores:
    print(name, score, sep=', ')
```

Text File Contents:

```
Ben, 12
Ben, 6
Ben, 3
Ben, 21
Ben, 1
```

How I want it to output:

```
Ben, 1
Ben, 3
Ben, 6
Ben, 12
Ben, 21
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4183506/1364007 maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'reverse' keyword.

```
scores.sort(key=lambda s: s[2], reverse=True)
```

Or:

```
scores.sort(key=lambda s: -s[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reverse` kwarg of the `sort` fonction.
Set it to `True` will reverse your list.