# How to sort a number from biggest to the lowest?

Tags: python

I want to make number sorter that can sort number:
Input:
90213
Output:
93210
Here is my code:

```
broj = int(input())
b = [broj]
print(b.sort(reverse=True))
```

When it runs it outputs None.

Comment: Welcome! Sort does not return any value, that is why you get None. You need to print the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list sort in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```py
broj = input()

print(''.join(sorted(broj, reverse=True)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert it to a int:

```
value = input()  # value is a string
sorted_value = sorted(value, reverse=True)  # sorted_value is a list like ['9', '3', '2', '1', '0']
print("".join(sorted_value))  # "".join() joins all the elements from the list to one string
```