# Extracting information from json file and then sorting using python

Tags: python, json, discord.py

[The Json file i want to extract "rank" information from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hVIk.png)

Basically I would like to get the top 10 ranks cryptocurrencies names.
each cryptocurrency has its rank in the given json screenshot.
is there anyway I can implement this in python?

Providing a link to the image shown
https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=demo-26240835858194712a4f8cc0dc635c7a

Comment: What do u need to extract.. Names only?

Comment: Yes, names only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import json

resp = requests.get(url = "https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker", params = {"key" :"demo-26240835858194712a4f8cc0dc635c7a"}) # Fetch response from API
resp = json.loads(resp.text)
final_names = []
for i in range(10): # JSON is ordered via Rank
    final_names.append(resp[i]["name"])

print(final_names) # Print final names
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!!*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
# your saved json response from API
file_path = "full/path/to/file.json"
with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    top_10_names = [x["name"] for x in data[:10]]
    # since the data is ordered by rank, 
    # you can take only the first 10 elements.
    print(top_10_names)
```

Comment: Hey, what if i wanted to order them in descending?

Comment: @aaryamann get the 10 lowest ranks you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Solution if cryptocurrencies **are not sorted by rank** by default in your json:

```py
import requests
from pprint import pprint

top_all = []
data = requests.get(url="https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker",
   params={"key": "demo-26240835858194712a4f8cc0dc635c7a"}).json()

for row in data:
    top_all.append({"name": row["name"], "rank": row["rank"]})

top_all = sorted(top_all, key=lambda x: int(x["rank"]))
pprint(top_all[0:10])
```

Comment: Hey, what if i wanted to order them in descending?

Comment: simply, change to `sorted(..., reverse=True)` (explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order)