# Print the index of the sorted list in unstable sorting technique

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I tried the following code:

```
import numpy
s = [6,6,6,6,6]
print(numpy.argsort(s))
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4]
```

Expected Output:
[4 3 2 1 0]

Another example sample code:

```
s = [5, 5, 2, 2, 3]
li = []

for i in range(len(s)):
    li.append([s[i], i])
li.sort()
sort_index = []

for x in li:
    sort_index.append(x[1])

print(sort_index)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
```

Expected Output:

```
[3 2 4 1 0]
```

Could this unstable sort index return is possible in python?

Comment: What is the reasoning behind your expected output?

Comment: Consider a scenario all elements are distinct in that case it should return the index of the sorted element from the original list.

Comment: When duplicate elements are present like [6,6,6,6,6,6] it should return the sorted list index from last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do something like:

```
>>> s = [5, 5, 2, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(enumerate(s), key=lambda x:(x[1], -x[0]))
[(3, 2), (2, 2), (4, 3), (1, 5), (0, 5)]
```

And if you just wanted the indices,

```
>>> [x[0] for x in sorted(enumerate(s), key=lambda x:(x[1], -x[0]))]
[3, 2, 4, 1, 0]
```

Or for your other example:

```
>>> s = [6,6,6,6,6]
>>> [x[0] for x in sorted(enumerate(s), key=lambda x:(x[1], -x[0]))]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Clever with the negative key element.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is sorting in reverse order. am I right? There is already a thread for that: [Python list sort in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order)
the function is
`list.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: Actually, I want the original index of the sorted list but in case a duplicate element is present it should return the index from last.