# Sort a range of values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a range of Salaries in a list in Python sth like this ['10,000-15,0000','2,500'-'3,000','5,000-7,500'].

I would like to sort this list asc but if try list.sort() it doesnt sort the proper away because the objects in list are strings.Ι cant convert to int and sort because
of the '-'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list sort in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  In particular, you have to define your problem.  You haven't specified what ordering you intend to impose on ranges, which do not have a natural ordering.  You also list an inconsistent string format; processing these into range notation of some sort will be your first task.

Comment: there is a sort function You can use. see more here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort

Comment: "I would like to sort this list but i cant find the proper way." What happened when you tried using any way at all? Exactly what result do you want for this input, and why (what is the rule that tells you which element goes before what)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of using a sort key that turns the first half of the string into an integer.

```
lst = ['10,000-15,0000','2,500-3,000','5,000-7,500']
lst.sort( key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0].replace(',','')))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
C:\Data>python x.py
['2,500-3,000', '5,000-7,500', '10,000-15,0000']

C:\Data>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim , this works for me , i am new to python and not used to lamba

Comment: IF you find it more understandable, you CAN move that into a standalone function, and pass the function name as the `key`.  It works exactly the same.  We Python nerds take too much pleasure into turning every problem into a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Main thing `['10,000-15,0000','2,500'-'3,000','5,000-7,500']`
this gives you an error...
But..
eg:
`arr = ['10000-15000','16000-20000','2500-3000']` #this can be sorted using below line
`arr = sorted(arr)`

Comment: Hello @Sanjay Kotabagi! This doesnt work it returns the same list as the first