# How to reverse a 2d list in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I sorted my list using `seq.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])` into `[[4, 0], [8, 0], [1, 0], [10, 0], [2, 2], [0, 2], [3, 3], [6, 3], [7, 3], [9, 3], [5, 4]]`, but i want it reversed like this `[[5, 4], [9, 3], [7, 3], [6, 3], [3, 3], [0 , 2], [2 ,2], [10, 0], [1, 0], [8, 0], [4, 0]]`. I've tried doing this `seq = seq[::-1]` , but doesn't work. It works if i store it in a new list `new_list = seq[::-1]`, but i want to use the same list `seq`.

Comment: `seq = seq[::-1]` should work.

Comment: What do you mean new list? I believe with seq[::-1] you are only getting a new reference, not a deep copy of the existing list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list sort in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183506/python-list-sort-in-descending-order) `list.sort()` takes a boolean `reverse` argument

Comment: Seems you’re trying to reverse the list not sort it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp)

You were on a good path with the sort() function, but the sort function just has an extra 'reverse' parameter which is `False` by default. Your code should be `seq.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: Weird...I tried that but, didn't work earlier. Now it works! Thanks! It maybe was the online editor i was using.